# Select statement from multi table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables (theUsers and Follows) in MySql and I am have the below query:

```
$sql=" SELECT u.* FROM theUsers u
INNER JOIN Follows ul ON ul.theUserLike = u.userName
WHERE ul.myUsername = '$userName' ORDER BY userName DESC";
```

The above sql is working perfect, what I need is to run it and to call all the users except one, This is what I have tried:

```
$sql=" SELECT u.* FROM theUsers u
INNER JOIN Follows ul ON ul.theUserLike = u.userName
WHERE ul.myUsername = '$userName' AND ul.myUsername <> 'admin' ORDER BY userName DESC";
```

But the result was null, Hope to find the answer with you.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Are you sure that there exists a row of myUsername as admin?

Comment: admin is a value in the row myUserName

Comment: How can myUsername be equal to $userName as well as admin? it can be only one at a time right?you have given AND condition where the myUsername can be $userName as well as admin

Comment: I take admin as an example, what is have her two tables ( one to save the users information and the other to save the followers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reason's why you are getting null is, since you are using `AND` both conditions needs to be true, if your follows table contain users that are admin then you are going to get null results, i don't see why you will get null if your follows table contains different users.

theUsers table

[image]

Follows table

[image: follows]

Your code will only work if your `theUsers` table contains a `userName` that is equal to `theUserLike` and `myUsername` in the `Follows` table

```
$userName = 'pete';
$sql=" SELECT u.* FROM theUsers u
INNER JOIN Follows ul ON ul.theUserLike = u.userName
WHERE ul.myUsername = '$userName' AND ul.myUsername <> 'admin' ORDER BY userName DESC";

$rst=$mysqli->query($sql);

$data = $rst->fetch_assoc();
while ($data != null) {
    echo $data['userName'];
    $data = $rst->fetch_assoc();
 }
```

> Outputs: pete

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the users except admin you can do that

```
$sql=" SELECT u.* FROM theUsers u
INNER JOIN Follows ul ON ul.theUserLike = u.userName
WHERE ul.myUsername <> 'admin' ORDER BY userName DESC";
```

You can change admin by $other_user, remenber that $other_user must be different to $userName

```
$sql=" SELECT u.* FROM theUsers u
INNER JOIN Follows ul ON ul.theUserLike = u.userName
WHERE ul.myUsername <> $other_user ORDER BY userName DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=" SELECT u.* FROM theUsers u
    INNER JOIN Follows ul ON ul.theUserLike = u.userName
    WHERE ul.myUsername <> 'admin' OR  ul.myUsername = '$userName' ORDER BY userName DESC";
```

Here we are checking the Not admin condition first and then the $userName condition with OR condition